# matchingFallbacks is deprecated in gradle 7.3.1

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-productflavors

The phrase 'matchingFallbacks is deprecated' is seen in `gradle 7.3.1`

What are the alternatives?

[[image: my setting1]

[image: gradle]

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's an issue with the docs, according to this: https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.3/com/android/build/api/dsl/BuildType#matchingFallbacks() this property is not deprecated. Even the pop up on your screenshot from Android Studio states that it was replaced with `matchingFallbacks`.

Comment: Seems to be deprecated in Android "kotlin" doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.3/com/android/build/api/dsl/BuildType#setMatchingFallbacks(kotlin.collections.List)

Comment: the setter is deprecated but the property still exists.